# Wrong number of type arguments when passing openssl::rsa::Rsa as a parameter

Tags: openssl, rust, rsa

I'm getting the following error when I try to pass a parameter to a function.

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:42:24
   |
42 | fn async_encrypt(rsa: &Rsa, plain: &str) -> String {
   |                        ^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

I believe it's because I'm defining a type but I don't know what type `openssl::rsa::Rsa` is other than itself.

```
extern crate openssl;
use openssl::rsa::Rsa;

fn main() {
    let plain = String::from("Well hello");
    let rsa = Rsa::generate(4096).unwrap();
    let cipher = async_encrypt(&rsa, &plain);
}

fn async_encrypt(rsa: &Rsa, plain: &str) -> String {
    //  Do some stuff
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `openssl`? [`openssl::rsa::Rsa`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.5/openssl/rsa/struct.Rsa.html) contains a parameter type T, which must be either `Public` or `Private`.

Comment: @E_net4 yep that did it, who know documentation could be so helpful ‍♀️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`openssl::rsa::Rsa`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.5/openssl/rsa/struct.Rsa.html) expects a parameter type `T`, which should be either [`Public`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.5/openssl/pkey/enum.Public.html) or [`Private`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.5/openssl/pkey/enum.Private.html). In turn, these types are markers for identifying the kind of key.

As the static method [`Rsa::generate`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.5/openssl/rsa/struct.Rsa.html#method.generate) yields a private key, you may want the following signature:

```
use openssl::pkey::Private;

fn async_encrypt(rsa: &Rsa<Private>, plain: &str) -> String {
    // ...
}
```

In the event that the function is supposed to work for both public and private keys, you can make it generic over `T`:

```
fn async_encrypt<T>(rsa: &Rsa<T>, plain: &str) -> String {
    // ...
}
```